# Upload Excel file, Display in Grid and Submit in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to upload an excel file, display the excel file data in grid and then submit the grid data in ASP.NET Core MVC. Please help to display the data in table grid and submit.

This is my code:

View

```
<input asp-for="FileUpload" class="form-control" />
<table id="dtFileUploadList" style="width:100%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Excel Data"></table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#FileUpload').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($("#FileUpload").val() == null) {
        return;
    }

    var files = e.target.files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
        formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("uploadedFile", files[i]);
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/UploadController/OnFileUpload",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                       //To bind the Json to the table
                    },
                    failure: function (result) {
                        toastr.error('File Upload Failed');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        toastr.error('File Upload Failed');
                    }
        });
    }
});
```

Contoller

```
[HttpPost]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public IActionResult OnFileUpload(IFormFile uploadedFile)
{
        if (uploadedFile == null)
        {
            return Json(new { data = "Files missing" });
        }

        if (Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
        {
           string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
           if (!Directory.Exists(path))
           {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
           }

           string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
           string filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

           using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
           {
               uploadedFile.CopyTo(stream);
           }

           string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           bool firstRow = true;

           foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
           {
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
               {
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                   {
                       if (firstRow)
                       {
                           foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                           {
                               dt.Columns.Add(cell.Trim());
                           }

                           firstRow = false;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           dt.Rows.Add();
                           int i = 0;

                           foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                           {
                               dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Trim();
                               i++;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           return Json(dt);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       return Json(new { data = "File Missing" });
   }
}
```

I'm getting the JSON datatable from controller to jQuery, how to bind that data to the table and show it along with header row data from Excel file. Also, please help me to submit, which datagrid I have to pass.

Comment: Confirm your needs with you. Do you want to transfer grid data to the database, and then display the data on the page. Is this the process?

Comment: First i want to display excel content on the page grid then i want to transfer the grid data(dtFileUploadList) to database.. After some research now I'm able to bind the excel data to grid table(dtFileUploadList) now i want to send this all rows to database